# Can we cover a close interval with disjoint close sets?

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that we can't represent  the close interval [0,1] as a union of א disjoint close intervals, when א is the cardinality of the real numbers.

Is this statement true or not?

Comment: Did you forget to mention that the intervals should be disjoint?

Comment: the statement that we can't do it is false, we can do it, just use singletons

Comment: False as stated, read @JensRenders comment.

Comment: The harder question about closed sets rather than closed intervals is dealt with elsewhere on this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is true for cardinality reasons. Any interval (not allowing one-point sets) contains a rational number, but there are only countably many rational numbers.